# Чтение одного и того же файла несколькими потоками на Fortran. Вызов процедур Fortran из C++, используя OpenMP

Tags: c++, многопоточность, файлы, openmp, fortran

С помощью "**OpenMP**" на C++ я создаю несколько потоков, каждый их которых вызывает некие одинаковые процедуры на Фортране, которые работают с одними и теми же файлами (не изменяют их! только читают). Так вот, у меня постоянно возникают ошибки чтения файла (то формат данных в файле не тот, то ещё что-нибудь). Но если я то же самое буду делать, но в однопоточном режиме, то всё нормально работает, никаких ошибок нет. Так вот, я и подумал, что, может быть, в Фортране нельзя один и тот же файл одновременно читать несколькими потоками? Ну, или что-то в этом роде. Я не знаю Фортрана, но приходится его подключать к C++, по ходу и разбираюсь. Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Для таких вопросов следует ставить метку `для телепатов`.

Comment: @user7860670, это сарказм или реально надо такую метку ставить? Если первое, то я не могу здесь привести код, так как он слишком большой.... Да и вопрос тут не зависит от кода, так как это вопрос о специфике работы Фортрана

Comment: ¿Вы всерьез рассчитываете, что читающие телепатическим усилием угадают, что вы там делаете и какие ошибки получаете? *"я не могу здесь привести код, так как он слишком большой"* - поэтому прежде, чем задавать вопрос, надо было составить [mcve].

Comment: С большой вероятностью, в Ваших фортрановских процедурах используются глобальные переменные, а это дело как-то совсем не дружит с многопоточностью.

Comment: @user7860670, зачем для ответа на вопрос "Можно ли в Фортране одновременно один и тот же файл читать несколькими потоками сразу?" приводить какой-то пример? Это вопрос без привязки к конкретному коду

Comment: @Vladimir, я для всех common-блоков и save-переменных прописал `!$OMP THREADPRIVATE`

Comment: Ответ на вопрос *"Можно ли в Фортране одновременно один и тот же файл читать несколькими потоками сразу?"* тривиальный: можно. Но у вас-то вопрос в том, что у вас получается неправильно.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, это я и хотел узнать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если будут фиксированы "юниты", то тогда не получится корректно читать один и тот же файл одновременно несколькими потоками. То есть если вот эту функцию из кода ниже вызывать одновременно из нескольких потоков, то в лучшем случае просто неверно в каждом потоке будет считываться информация, а в худшем просто будет аварийно завершаться работа.

```
           SUBROUTINE read_ig_rz(path, il)

           integer  iyst,iyend,iymst,iupd,iupm,iupy,imst,imend
           real     aig(806),arz(806)
           character(len=il)  :: path

           common /igrz/aig,arz,iymst,iymend
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/igrz/)

           open(unit=12,file=path//'ig_rz.dat',
     & FORM='FORMATTED',status='old')

            read(12,*) iupd,iupm,iupy
            read(12,*) imst,iyst,imend,iyend

            iymst=iyst*100+imst
            iymend=iyend*100+imend

            inum_vals= 3-imst+(iyend-iyst)*12 +imend

            read(12,*) (aig(i),i=1,inum_vals)
            read(12,*) (arz(i),i=1,inum_vals)

            if(iupy*100+iupm.gt.201609) then
                inum_chan= 3-imst+(2014-iyst)*12
                do 1 jj=inum_chan,inum_vals
                    arz(jj)=arz(jj)*0.7
1                   continue
                endif
            close(unit=12)

            return
            END
```

Поэтому те участки кода, в которых происходят открытие, чтение и закрытие файла, нужно оборачивать в директиву `!$omp critical`.